# For some reason my java class won't inherit a public void. Can somebody help me?

Tags: java, android

I'm pretty much new to Java development and I'm trying to build a simple android game, for this, I need to inherit some methods from other classes. Only, for some reason it won't. Am I missing something here?

Here is code from the public Java class "Addition"

```
public class Addition {
    Random random = new Random();

    int Answer;
    int PartOne;
    int PartTwo;
    int FalseAnswer;

    //CALL IN THIS FIRST!

    public void Calculate() {
        Answer = random.nextInt(999) + 2;
        PartTwo = random.nextInt(Answer--) + 1;
        PartOne = Answer - PartTwo;
        FalseAnswer = random.nextInt(Math.round(Answer * 1.2f)) + Math.round(Answer * 0.8f);
    }
```

//some more stuff.

Here is the class subtraction, that I want to base upon Addition. Here is the code that I have there:

```
    public class Subtraction{
    Addition addition = new Addition();
    addition.Calculate();
}
```

Don't mind the formatting, it is just to demonstrate. It is giving me an error, saying Calculate does not exist or cannot be found (neither can the other methods in the class).

I have also already tried inherting directly:

```
public class Subtraction extends Addition{
    Calculate();
}
```

Didn't work either. The only thing it let's me do is this:

```
public class Subtraction extends Addition{
    @Override
    public void Calculate() {
        super.Calculate();
    }
}
```

Which is not what I want. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can someone please point it out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calling addition.Calculate outside of an executional context (like a method or constructor) is illegal, that's why your first two examples don't work. You only need to extend Addition, then any instance of Subtraction will be able to call Calculate

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Subtraction extends Addition{

}
```

is all you need. Don't write `Calculate();` in that class, you've already inherited it.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you can't call methods like that outside of any class method. That' why this would work

```
public class Subtraction extends Addition{
    @Override
    public void Calculate() {
        super.Calculate(); // calls the 'calculate' method of the 'Addition' class
    }
}
```

& this won't:

```
public class Subtraction extends Addition{
    Calculate(); // Outside of any method, invalid call
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't trying to inherit from the Addition class using:

```
public class Subtraction extends Addition
{
    @Override
    public void Calculate()
    {
        super.Calculate(); // calls the 'calculate' method of the 'Addition' class
    }
}
```

Then you need to put

```
Addition addition = new Addition();
addition.Calculate();
```

into a method that can be called. Do it like this:

```
public class Subtraction
{
    public void Calculate()
    {
        Addition addition = new Addition();
        addition.Calculate();
    }
}
```

You have to do it this way because the method calls have to be in an executable context (in a method or constructor).